# access fields same but not equal?

Tags: ms-access, vba

i'm using the following code to compare two recordsets:

```
For i = 1 To (recordsetA.Fields.Count - 1)
    If recordsetA.Fields(i).Value <> recordsetB.Fields(i).Value Then
        stringFieldList = stringFieldList & ", " & recordsetA.Fields(i).Name
    End If
Next i
```

However in the stringFieldList there are a couple of fields which have the same values (like 1339.5). Why?

Comment: First, What values are they? Second have you considered the handling of trailing spaces? Fields with trailing spaces generally compare equal within the DB but unequal in C# or other languages.

Comment: Just to clarify: (1) Do you mean "a couple of fields whose names appear in stringFieldList, but for which the values in the two recordsets are the same"? (2) How do you know they're the same? I mean, have you just eyeballed them, or have you checked carefully character by character in your code, or what?

Comment: @Ben i have not considered the handling of trailing spaces. Could you give some examples on how to deal with them? @Gareth McCaughan to the first question: Yes. to the second question. I've just opened the table and compared the allegedly different fields manually. Actually the fields are of double number. They are not empty and look identical at all.

Comment: I suggest comparing Trim(<value> & ""), to avoid problems with null.

Comment: A code note: this would be slimmer code using a For/Each loop and a variable of type DAO.Field.

Answer (score 3):

Since it sounds like your dealing with double datatypes, the proper way for the test would be to set a limit, then test the absolute difference.  You will also need to think about handling a null value.

```
Const epsilon as double = 0.00001

If Abs(recordsetA.Fields(i).Value - recordsetB.Fields(i).Value) < epsilon Then
'do stuff here
End If
```

Comment: Indeed. Doubles can be non-equal in the high-order decimal places (_very_ small difference), while appearing equal in the displayed representation.